# Can't access my localhost via internet

Tags: xampp, ip, port, router, server

- forward port 80 TCP/UDP on router (OPENED)
- port 80 TCP/UDP on firewall (OPENED)
- httpd.conf - httpd-xampp.conf (EDITED)

But when I try visiting by my ip I get nothing on browser,
its working on LAN and WLAN not on internet

- What I should to do?
- there better way to make PC as webserver?
- which is best OS for server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ISPs won't allow port 80 to be connected to from outside your home network as an attempt to block people from hosting a website from their home network.  Try setting your server to listen on a different port (85 is generally not in use) and you should be able to connect to it.

As for your other question, in my opinion, Ubuntu (or any flavor of Linux) is a good OS for a web server.  Ubuntu is free and easy to use and there are plenty of resources online if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I have tried a lot of ports but I get nothing!

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue on the server. What does sudo iptables -L -n give you?